# Need to run a program if a hard drive fails using Mega-raid software

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008, software-raid

I am hoping to run a program when a hard drive fails. I am using Mega-raid software on a windows server 2008.

I was thinking of using windows event viewer, to run a program when an event comes in on the application log.

However I am unsure what event ID is used.

Or if there is an easier way please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up all the megaRAID event ID's in the [MegaRAID user's manual](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mega-raid%20event%20ids&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/Storage%2520Products/Internal%2520RAID/embedded_mr_sw_ug.pdf&ei=Ncq0UePhMKSsyAH8soCACw&usg=AFQjCNEXEDqEO72_HTEw_GETNQrcIDCUWA&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aWc) from LSI.

Specifically check out *Appendix A: Events and  Messages*.

I'd suspect you mainly want to monitor events 249-252 to get changes in the status of the RAID (Optimal vs. Degraded vs. Offline), but there are several others that you also may want to monitor that can help identify problems with the RAID/volumes/drives before a full failure.

Additionally, you can get the *MegaRAID Storage Manager* from LSI, and it can be setup to email you on RAID events (amongst other things, like SNMP).

Comment: thank you very much for this. I have set up a scheduled task with three triggers looking at the application Log, Hope this does the trick!